# Would gauntlets with claws be an effective weapon?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, weapons, armors

I am coming up with a kind of weapon a supervillain builds himself with fairly modern materials/tech. He uses it as a weapon, but also as a device for lacerating and torturing his victims.

I’m imagining a kind of steel glove with long claws (maybe 3-4 inches) on the fingertips. Each finger joint has a little gear, sort of like a park gear on an automatic transmission, that can either rotate freely or be locked in place at fixed points along the rotation of the joint. Each joint, including the base of each finger and the wrist, would have this mechanism, restricting its freedom of movement somewhat but allowing for the fingers not to break and dislocate when “slashing” with the claws by locking them up. I was thinking the glove may even extend past the elbow, having another locking gear on the elbow so it doesn’t break or buckle. Ideally, whenever any joint is unlocked and moved about, it would make an ominous “clicking” noise like a free-spinning bicycle gear, so extra points if that can happen.

Assuming the villain has very strong fingers, would this be an effective weapon/torture device with a bit of hand-waving, or is it too complicated/too much risk of pinching fingers? How could the design be improved/made more brutal?

Comment: If this villain can haunt his victims' dreams, this can get really scary.

Comment: If villain is extra itchy (e.g. scabies) but cannot get ivermectin (none left) that could explain the provenance of this claw.

Answer (score 1):

i dont quite understand your mechanism, but claw gauntlet did exist historically, and base on your description, it sound like this to me (in purely non mechanical).

[image]
from:pinterest

mostly a weapon or armor for dueling rather than for warfare, as it can help to claw opponent and catch opponents blade, because the palm part usually are made of chainmail.

and if this is not clear, this weapon or gauntlet armor typically use by finger or claw user martial arts against other weapon martial arts.

so i say yes? if what i interpret it is correct.

otherwise if you mean something like xmen wolverine claw, then i would suggest to form the blade like katar as V.Aggarwal already bring up or change it into single blade and use karate chop to slash, or make it short enough and bend it like carnivore claw rather than sword like, or make it a bit thicker rather than blade like teko kagi.

[image]
from:https://www.yamatobudogu.com/products/tekko-kagi

oh yeah i forgot to add, since we are dealing with mechanical contraption and likely dealing with blood and meat chunk, you likely need to clean it thoroughly after use, if you dont want the mechanical thing getting rust or glued by the dried blood, that can make some of them stuck or malfunction.

Comment: The first glove is pretty close. The mechanism is there because I would worry about thin human fingers buckling/breaking if you slashed something with it, so the fingers on the glove could lock in place, taking the stress off of the fingers. Apologies if it was hard to understand.

Comment: @MarkPrice well if it slash like how hand slap or stab/poke using your fingertip, i can see that happen (assuming it hit hard object rather than squishy body parts) but i dont think making it rigid help either (infact i think it make it worse, except in the stab or poking one, my advice is keep the finger relax, its tougher than you think).

Answer (score 0):

**Katar**

What you are referring to is very close to a Katar (Except the rotating blade part).

Katar is an ancient Indian Weapon of Rajput, used for close quarters and their favorite past-time Tiger hunting.
It is basically a gauntlet with a blade on it, and some versions of it had a mechanism of opening and closing the blade.

It would hurt really bad if someone is stabbed in the gut and then the blades are opened and closed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An example from fiction: [The Warhammer 40K Lightning Claw](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Lightning_Claw).

[image]

Comment: This seems close if I understand it correctly, just with the claws on the fingertips instead.